# How would I go about limiting a users action utilizing Parse?

Tags: swift, parse-platform

This is all purely for educational purposes, to help me get a better understanding of how Parse as well as Swift operates.

I would like to make it so a user is only able to like an item once (not being able to hit a button multiple times), as currently, I'm utilizing an anonymous system with Parse.

Would I essentially use an if method with PFUser.CurrentUser() in the likeButton method to halt a user from hitting like again or would I use NSUserDefaults?

I'm not able to post code currently as I'm not near my laptop, however I could later if it helps. Still curious if I could get some info before that however.

Sample code I found on here from a previous question, which essentially implements the same idea.

```
@IBAction func likeButton(sender: AnyObject) {
    let hitPoint = sender.convertPoint(CGPointZero, toView: self.tableView)
    let hitIndex = self.tableView.indexPathForRowAtPoint(hitPoint)
    let object = objectAtIndexPath(hitIndex)
    object.incrementKey("count")
    object.saveInBackground()
    self.tableView.reloadData()   
}
```

Would I call NSUsersDefaults to stunt the user from hitting it more than once?

Comment: It does help to post code - see stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: that depends on what you want. NSUserdefaults if the device can only like it once, Current user if you want each account to only like it once (but people can really easily make a new account)

Comment: @milo526 added come code

Answer (score 0):

Instead of calling `saveInBackground()`, you'd better call the method `saveInBackgroundWithBlock:` instead. So the strategy is very simple:

First of all, define a 'busy' flag for the object (For example: `savingInBackground`) and store it wherever you like ( If you are showing 1 item then simply declare a `Bool` property / If you are showing a list of Item then declare a `Dictionary` with format ["objectID/Index": Bool]). This flag should be set to `true` for the item being saved in the background.

Whenever use taps on a Like button

1. If current item's `savingInBackground` flag is `true`, then do nothing
2. Else:

   1. Set item's `savingInBackground` to `true`
   2. Increase Like count and Call `saveInBackgroundWithBlock:`
   3. In the completion block of `saveInBackgroundWithBlock:`, set `savingInBackground` back to `false`.

I am on train now so I can't write example code, but I hope that it's clear enough to help you to achieve what you want.